# Create timer in Node js that reset after every 10 minute, and also return the current minutes when hit the api

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create an API in Node js that return the time in minutes.
When server start running, timer will also start. that timer will reset after every 10 minute. 
When I hit the API then the current time of timer should return.
Like the current time in timer is **06:42** (6 minutes and 42 seconds) it will be response of API.
when timer reach to **09:59** then it reset to **00:00**

Please help me in this problem. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script should do what you require, we record the time once we start the app, then reset every timer interval.

```
const port = 8080;
const app = express();
const timerDurationSeconds = 10 * 60;

let timerStart = new Date().getTime();

/* Reset the timer on each interval. */
setInterval(() => { 
    console.log("Resetting timer...");
    timerStart = new Date().getTime();
}, timerDurationSeconds * 1000);

app.get('/timer', function(req, res) {
    let elapsedSeconds = (new Date().getTime() - timerStart) / 1000;
    let minutes = Math.floor(elapsedSeconds / 60 ).toFixed(0).padStart(2, "0");
    let seconds = Math.round(elapsedSeconds % 60).toFixed(0).padStart(2, "0");
    res.send( `${minutes}:${seconds}`);
})

app.listen(port);
console.log(`Serving at http://localhost:${port}`);
```

Calling

```
curl http://localhost:8080/timer
```

should show the response.

This will look like (for example):

```
01:22
```

Comment: What If a want to reverse it. timer start from 10:00 and countdown. like API hit after 10 second and response will be 09:50

Comment: did this and it worked.
let elapsedSeconds = ((timerStart - new Date().getTime()) + 600000) / 1000;

Comment: That makes sense@